# ActionBar Menu Items Icon sizes are not working properly

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have re-sized the icon according to drawables like: 32px, 48px,96px, etc.

But when running the app it is showing the bigger image. Is there anything else that I have to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Where have you placed the images?

Comment: I had placed images in drawable folders like ldpi, hdpi, mdpi, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct size for `ActionBar` menu icons:

```
drawable-ldpi - 16 × 16 area in 16 × 16

drawable-mdpi - 24 × 24 area in 32 × 32

drawable-hdpi - 36 × 36 area in 48 × 48

drawable-xhdpi - 48 × 48 area in 64 × 64

drawable-xxhdpi - 72 × 72 area in 96 × 96

drawable-xxxhdpi - 96 × 96 area in 128 × 128
```

The first number is the size of the icon area, and the second is file size.

Comment: I had placed in their respective folders. like you

Comment: it is working...after changing pixels to 24px for mdpi,16px for ldpi, 32px for hdpi, so on..

Comment: Here is the right way for android all icons  - http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

Comment: Your way is also right but you didn't give me area size for icons

Comment: @SurenderKumar: Thanks for the link, that was nice. I have edited the answer accordingly.